# How to use replaceState() instead of pushState()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, history.js

I have implemented `History.js` with `History.pushState` fuction. Here is code below:

```
function PushStateUrl(stateUrl) {
  manualStateChange = false;
  History.pushState({ loadUrl: stateUrl, rand: Math.random() }, document.title, stateUrl);
}
```

And on browser's back button, this code executes:

```
$(function () {
 History.Adapter.bind(window, "statechange", function () {
 var State = History.getState();
 var url = ((State.data.loadUrl == "undefined") ? State.data.loadUrl : State.url);
 if (typeof (manualStateChange) !== "undefined" && manualStateChange == true) {
    AjaxCall(url);
}
else if (typeof (State.data.loadUrl) == "undefined") {
    AjaxCall(url);
}
 manualStateChange = true;
 });    
});
```

But I want to use `replaceState()` instead of `pushState()`. Please guide me to what changes needs to use `history.replaceState()`

Answer (score 0):

> But I want to use replaceState() instead of pushState(). Please guide me to what changes needs to use history.replaceState()

Change the word `push` to `replace` in your code. The two functions take the same arguments.

Obviously, if you do that *everywhere*, then your code for handling the back button becomes redundant (because you are never going to be going back to a stored state).